# Cypress browser recorder

Tags: cypress

Does Cypress have browser recorder tool like Katalon is for Selenium? It seems that may be quicker to write tests. It would make tests easier for non-technical team members to maintain and easier and quicker to setup and automate.

Comment: If you add this to your cypress.json file you will get video from your `npx cypress run` runs: `"video": true`, Also for debugging there is a complete ui with command `npx cypress open` Not sure if that is what you are asking for

Comment: No. I was looking to see if anyone has created tool to automate creation of Cypress tests. It would make it easier on non-technical crew to setup ide, nodejs, and install Cypress.  Katalon allows you to record actions, modify test, and run in browser. You can then share tests with team members. The tests can then be run on a schedule using other products.

Comment: @user3763268 Are you looking for something like you interact with the UI and equivalent code is generated ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Preflight's Cypress recorder.

https://cypress.preflight.com

It creates very good css and xpath selectors. Scripts also adapt to UI changes.

Email, visual, sms and pdf testing is also available.

I just tried email testing, it took me 2 minutes to create a Cypress script

Answer (score 1):

There are several browser plugins that allow recording cypress commands but none of them looks like a powerful tool which can be compared to Katalon recorder.

Beside that, there is a couple of solutions that I believe can compete with the Katalon one:

1. There is a [Cypress Studio tool](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/cypress-studio) (though it's still marked as    'experimental'). It works inside the Cypress runner itself.
2. For IntelliJ platform, there is a paid plugin 'Cypress Pro' which
   integrates recorder with the IDE. Here is a [tutorial video](https://youtu.be/FgnHYwmguFI)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.dakka.dev/ - is a chrome extension for generating tests for Cypress.io.

It also supports the assertions and suggests element selectors which are closer to how we write end-to-end tests.

It also supports Playwright and Puppeteer

here's the direct link to the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dakka/gllikifiancbeplnkdnpnmmhhlncghej

Answer (score 0):

No there is no capture+replay capability present in cypress. However, you must consider that the captured and auto-generated tests in Katalon can become messy and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

It is not as powerful as Katalon, but there are chrome extensions which can record actions and generate Cypress code -- can be useful to get started with tests, although you'll still need to write the assertions.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cypress-recorder/glcapdcacdfkokcmicllhcjigeodacab
https://github.com/KabaLabs/Cypress-Recorder

Until someone (Cypress?) makes a more complete recorder/code generator I'm confident recommending it, but as @Ivan said it's not as complex or feature-rich at Katalon.